# Error migrating Android app from Delphi 10.4 to 11.3

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, migration

I don't program much but wanted to update a little program I wrote for my phone using Delphi 10.4 community edition.
When I try deploy (deug mode) in 11.3 I get the following error:

Hoping someone can help

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute '"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.48361.3236\build-tools\32.0.0\Aapt.exe" package -f -M "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\AndroidManifest.xml" -F "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\bin\ScrabbleScorer-unaligned.apk" -I "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.48361.3236\platforms\android-32\android.jar" -S "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\res" -A "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\assets" "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\library" "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\delphi\Android\Debug\ScrabbleScorer\classes"' (Error 1)

Tried loading small project that deployed fine with 10.4 into 11.3 - it wont deploy

Comment: Have you verified that all the paths of that command are correct? Those utilities are where indicated (aapt.exe, android.jar,...)?

Comment: Delete AndroidManifest.template.xml. If you made any customizations to that file, you'll need to make sure you re-apply them once you recompile the app. You will probably need to follow [these steps, too](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/HowTo/tree/main/Solutions/AndroidLibraries).

Comment: Thank you. Noticed platforms was not there so did: sdkmanager.bat --install "platforms;android-32"